# Javascript Diagonal Matrix

Tags: javascript, matrix, multidimensional-array

I need to do a simple diagonal matrix in JS, which should look like this  one:

```
[
  [4, 7, 9],
  [2, 5, 8],
  [1, 3, 6]
]
```

My idea is to use a 2-d array and two loops, but the result I get is an empty array.You'll see below what my code looks like, but obviously I have a problem with the values.

```js
function fillMatrix(n) {
  var matrix = [];
  var rows = 0;
  var cols = 0;
  var startCount = 1;

  for (var i = (n - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
    rows = i;
    cols = 0;
    matrix[rows] = [];
    while (rows < n && cols < n) {

      matrix[rows++][cols++] = startCount++;
    }


    for (var j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      rows = j;
      cols = 0;
      matrix[rows] = [];
      while (rows < n && cols < n) {
        matrix[cols++][cols++] = startCount++;
      }
    }
  }
  return matrix;
}

n = +prompt();
console.log(fillMatrix(n));
```

Comment: I'm not sure what a "diagonal matrix" is or what you're code is trying to do. Could you add some explanation as to how it's meant to work, and some example inputs/expected outputs?

Comment: Hello, this is what I mean about the "diagonal matrix"[link](https://nikola76.files.wordpress.com/2013/02/table3.png?w=300&h=236). The idea is to input the number of rows/cols (n) and print in the console an array in this order: [4,7,9] [2,5,8] [1,3,6];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic for creating a diagonal matrix can be greatly simplified if one looks at the patterns between rows. (I won't go through all of the math here, but feel free to ask me questions in the comments about any specific sections you find confusing.)

Take, for example, the 4x4 diagonal matrix:

[image]

Successive differences between elements in a row form the pattern below:

[image]

I might still work on shortening the method below, but right now it works and is fairly concise.

### Demo:

```js
function diagonalMatrix (n) {
  var matrix = [], row
  for (var i = n; i > 0; i--) {
    var x = i*(i-1)/2 + 1, dx = i
    matrix.push(row = [])
    for (var j = n; j > 0; j--) {
      row.push(x)
      x += (i < j ? ++dx : dx--)
    }
  }
  return matrix
}

var matrix = diagonalMatrix(+prompt('Diagonal Matrix Order:'))

console.log(beautify(matrix))
console.log(matrix)



// For visualization purposes
function beautify (matrix) {
  return matrix.map(function (e) {
    return e.join('\t')
  }).join('\n\n\n\n')
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100vh; }
```